# How can I show a different image if the URL string end with **.pdf** in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have the following problem working on an Angular application. Into my HTML code I have something like this:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-file>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img class="img-thumbnail" src={{file.info.file_url}}/>
      </td>
      ............................................................
      ............................................................
      ............................................................
```

So as you can see I am using the **img** tag in order to show an image from an URL. The problem is that sometimes this URL is not an image but it could be a PDF file. In this case the image is not shown and I obtain something like this:

[image]

So what I want to di is:

I have put a PDF icon image into the **/src/assets/img/pdf.png** folder of my project.
I want to check (if possible into the previous html code using something like *ngIf directive) if the **file.info.file_url** property value end with **.pdf** and in case use this **/src/assets/img/pdf.png** instead the value of the **file.info.file_url** property.

How can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
function isPdf(file) {
  const extension = file.substr((file.lastIndexOf('.') +1));
  return /(pdf)$/ig.test(extension)
}
```

...

```
  <td>
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="{{isPdf(file.info.file_url) ? '/src/assets/img/pdf.png' : file.info.file_url}}" />
  </td>
```